# Is it possible to use Logstash to remove_field if it does not match a certain value?

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

We want to filter a log using Logstash by removing fields if the field does not contain "_log". The `remove_field` syntax is available, but only works for removing a field if it matches a certain condition.

```
filter {
  grok {
    remove_field => [ "log_" ]
  }
}
# This works for removing the log_ field, we want to remove everything that does NOT match log_.
```

Is it also possible to remove a field if it does not match a certain condition?

We tried using a regex that did just that, but that did not work (is it documented somewhere that you cannot use a regex?). Removing all *other* fields is also an option, but way more effort. We hope someone can help us fitering all fields that do not contain "log_".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regexp should work:

```
filter {
  if [field] !~ /pattern/ {
    mutate {
      remove_field => [ "field" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do we have the option to give regular expressions for all the fields? I have 10-30 fields with word createdBy - How can I remove all fields which contains this field

Comment: @JinnaBalu unless they've added something new, you'd need to drop into ruby for that.  Lots of examples here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways you can do it is..

- Tag the fields that do not match the condition (using `tag_on_failure`)
- Remove the above tagged fields

Example:-

```
grok {
    match => ["log_"]
    tag_on_failure => ["_todelete"]
}
```

and then

```
grok {
    remove_tag => [ "_todelete" ]
}
```